# What distinguishes a Lewis Complex from an Adduct or are they synonymous?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I cannot think of a distinction - the terms seem to be used interchangeably when talking about products of Lewis acid-base reactions. However, I am concerned that I may have overlooked a subtlety. Please can you clarify?